# Prevent short-circuiting in Bash

Tags: bash, short-circuiting

I want to

1. generate a list of matching files
2. know if at least one of the patterns matched

The following will not work if there are any pdf files because then the first `compgen` will return `true` and the second `compgen` will not be executed.

```
{ compgen -G "*.pdf" || compgen -G "*.txt"; }
```

Is there a way to prevent short-circuiting?

Comment: So don't use `||`?

Comment: @KamilCuk Using `;` would just return the result of the last compgen. I still need the logical or of all the compgens to know if there was any match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Using ; would just return the result of the last compgen. I still need the logical or of all the compgens to know if there was any match.

You can write logic to handle exit status yourself. A short version could look likethe following:

```
{ cmd1; ret=$?; cmd2; ! ((ret | $?)); }
```

Answer (score 6):

Use an [extended glob pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching#:%7E:text=extglob).

```
shopt -s extglob
compgen -G '*.@(pdf|txt)'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```sh
files=( *.pdf *.txt )
compgen -W "${files[*]}"
```

This breaks with files containing whitespace, but tricks can be played with IFS to work around that.